# How to set x_ticks rotation in subplots using matplotilib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am using matplotlib subplots to create two plots side by side. 
Here is the code I am using

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = py.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(16, 6))
fig.suptitle('Trips percentage per daira (for the top 10 dairas)', size = 16)

py.xticks(rotation = 90)
ax = sns.barplot(x = df.p_daira.value_counts().nlargest(10).index, 
            y = df.p_daira.value_counts().nlargest(10) / df.shape[0] * 100,
                 ax = ax0)
ax.set(xlabel='Pickup Daira', ylabel='Trips percentage')
ax.set_xticks(rotation=90)

#py.xticks(rotation=90)
ax = sns.barplot(x = df.d_daira.value_counts().nlargest(10).index, 
            y = df.d_daira.value_counts().nlargest(10)/df.shape[0] * 100
                 , ax = ax1)
ax.set(xlabel='Dropoff Daira', ylabel='Trips percentage')

py.show()
```

Here is the result I am getting : 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlYOB.png)

Even that I set the x_ticks rotation to 90 degrees, it applies only to the second plot!

In there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Please include the imports `from matplotlib import pyplot as py` and `import seaborn as sns` etc. to make this a runable code. Please also fill in some demo data in `pd` so the code can run standalone.

Comment: You only do `ax.set_xticks(rotation=90)` once. Maybe you need to do it again for the other plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you write `py.xticks(rotation = 90)` we have to assume that you imported `matplotlib.pyplot as py` (which is possible but normally abbreviated different, namely `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`).

However, having said that, please note that using the methods of `pyplot` (i.e. `py` in your case), you always automatically refer to the *current active axes*, which is usually the last created one.

If you want to explicitely call functions of certain axes, use their object notation, like

```
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)
ax2.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)
```

---

Note that if you wonder where this should lead to when creating more subplots like 3x3 or more, you'd rather store them all in an array like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3)
```

and then access the single axes by indexing the array, e.g.

```
axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axs[1, 0].plot(z)
```

or

```
for ax in axs.flatten():
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)
```